# Tetris Tangrams

Tags: code-challenge, optimization, tetris, packing

### Introduction

[Tangrams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangram) are a classic puzzle involving arranging/fitting blocks into various shapes.  From the Chinese 七巧板 - literally meaning "seven boards of skill".  Let's take this idea and use the seven [Tetrominos](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetris#Gameplay) pieces to fill a grid.

### Challenge

Write a function or program that takes an array of grid coordinates as input, and outputs a completed 10 by 20 grid filled with Tetris pieces except in the specified coordinates.

Optimize your score by attempting to keep the distribution of pieces uniform.

### Criteria

Use [this pastebin](http://pastebin.com/0QAgFT5f) of coordinates to accomplish your task.  There are five sets of coordinates.  Feel free to modify the format in which the coordinates are written, but not the values.

Data set #2 cannot be solved - in this case, simply output the grid with input cells filled in (i.e., `X`'s where the holes are).

### Input

Grid coordinates represent 'holes' in the grid.  These are cells which cannot contain any part of a Tetromino.

**Grid coordinates:**

```
(0,0), (1,0), (2,0), ... (9,0)
(0,1), (1,1), (2,1), ... (9,1)
.
.
.
(0,19), (1,19), (2,19), ... (9,19)
```

- Use your programming language's array style of choice to input the coordinates.
- Represent holes in the grid with an `X` or other [printable ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_printable_characters).

### Output

Using a standard Tetris grid size of **10 cells wide by 20 cells tall**, print a solution grid if and only if the grid can be filled completely and perfectly using Tetromino pieces.

Pieces constructed with letters `I`, `O`, `L`, `J`, `T`, `Z`, `S` as follows:

```
I          
I          L      J
I    OO    L      J     T     ZZ      SS
I    OO    LL    JJ    TTT     ZZ    SS
```

---

### Example

Output solution example with no input coordinates:

```
ZZIIIILLLI
JZZTTTLLLI
JJJSTLOOLI
SZZSSLOOLI
SSZZSLLJJI
TSOOSLLJII
TTOOSSLJII
TZOOSSLZII
ZZOOSSZZII
ZJJJJSZLLI
TTTJJOOILI
ITZJJOOILI
IZZTTTLIII
IZOOTZLIII
IJOOZZLLII
LJJJZSSTII
LLLTSSTTTI
LLLTTSSZJI
OOLTSSZZJI
OOIIIIZJJI
```

With distribution as follows:

```
I          
I          L      J
I    OO    L      J     T     ZZ      SS
I    OO    LL    JJ    TTT     ZZ    SS

11   6     8     6      6     7      6
```

---

### Notes

Coordinates represent a single `X` and `Y` position on the grid.  The grid is 0 based, meaning coordinate `(0,0)` should either be the top left or the bottom left cell, author's choice.

Bricks can:

- be selected at author's discretion.
- be rotated as author sees fit.
- be placed on the grid anywhere at author's discretion (aka: no Tetris gravity)

Bricks cannot:

- be placed outside the bounds of the grid.
- overlap an existing brick or hole in the grid.
- be a non-standard Tetris tetromino piece.

---

### Scoring

Your score is in the format:

**( 1000 - [bytes in code] ) * ( M / 10 + 1 )**

Where M is a multiplier for the distribution of pieces used in your solution sets.

Highest score by the Ides of March wins.

To calculate M, add the lowest individual tetromino distribution value for each set and then take the average rounded down to calculate M.

For example:

```
Set 1: 5
Set 2: 4
Set 3: 5
Set 4: 6
Set 5: 3
```

6 + 4 + 5 + 4 + 4 = 21 / 5 = 4.6

So you would use `4` as your **M** value.

Note: If a set has no solution, do not factor that set into calculating M, since it would have no tetromino distribution.

Comment: Improving questions after they are posted is generally difficult, because if the changes are substantial they will invalidate work of people who have already started working on the problem (or worse, even posted the result). I would recommend posting challenge ideas [in the sandbox](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2140/8478). *That* is the place to ask for feedback and polish the spec before it goes on main. That being said, after a quick skim, I didn't see any glaring problems with your challenge.

Comment: @MartinBüttner Duly noted, thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Ides of March = 15 of March. I had to look that up.

Comment: I've made some small changes to front-load the task description, because otherwise it's impossible to understand what we're being asked to do on the first read-through. I think it would be an improvement if you stated which of the input cases can't be solved, so that they function as test cases in addition to a scoring dataset.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Fair enough, I've added which solution set cannot be solved.  Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Are there any standard algorithms for solving this kind of problem?

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 819 bytes, M=0, Score=*181*

This is a brute force DFS program. It builds a numpy array, and inserts all the inputted holes. It then takes the leftmost unfilled tile on the highest row that has one, and places a tetromino. Recursively, we now do it again - when we can't either we found a solution, or we backtrack and try another piece at the first opportunity.

This has an **M** of 0, since it tries to use pieces in a determined order, and almost always finds a solution without the last one in the list. I tried using a randomly ordered list each cycle to make a more even distribution, but I only got an **M** of 2, which wasn't worth the bytes required to import *random.shuffle*.

I can't comment the below code, since in my golfing I've long forgotten what much of it does. The general idea:

- Import numpy and itertools product, with 1-letter names
- Rename some builtins to be 1-letter functions, and define a lambda to save bytes
- Build the array of possible tetrominos as numpy nd-arrays, all rotations included
- In the recursive function:

  - Get the position of the unfilled tile desired, and cycle through the pieces list
  - For each piece, cycle through translations of it (moving it up and down)
  - If something doesn't work (piece goes off the board, hits another piece, hits a hole, etc.), try the next translation or the next entire piece
  - If it works, great. Try it, then recursively call the function.
  - If that path didn't work, it will return 'a', so we just try again. If it did work, it returns the board, and we pass it up the line.
- Finally, the program. We build the 10x20 board as a numpy array of 1's.
- The input is of the form *(x1, y1);(x2,y2);...* We put a 9 for each hole in it, then get the result of running the function on it.
- The print statement then displays either the successful result or the empty, original board line by line, substituting the appropriate letters or symbols for the numbers.

```python
import numpy as n
from itertools import product as e
m,s=range,len
p=[n.rot90(a,k)for a,r in[([[2,2]]*2,1),([[3]*3,[1,3,1]],4),([[0]*4],2),([[1,1,6],[6]*3],4),([[7,1,1],[7]*3],4),([[4,4,1],[1,4,4]],2),([[1,5,5],[5,5,1]],2)]for k in m(r)]
o=lambda a:e(m(s(a)),m(s(a[0])))
def t(l,d=0):
	g=list(zip(*n.where(l==1)))[0]
	for a in p:
		for u,v in o(a):
			w,x=l.copy(),0
			for r,c in o(a):
				if a[r,c]!=1:
					i,j=g[0]+r-u,g[1]+c-v
					if any([i<0,i>19,j<0,j>9])or l[i,j]!=1:
						x=1
						break
					w[i,j]=a[r,c]
			if x==0:
				if len(w[w==1]):
					f=t(w,d+1)
					if type(f)==str:continue
					return f
				return w
	return'a'
b=n.ones((20,10))
b[list(zip(*[eval(k)[::-1]for k in input().split(';')]))]=9
a=t(b)
for r in(a,b)[type(a)==str]:
	print(''.join(map(dict(zip([0,2,3,4,5,6,7,9,1],'IOTZSLJX-')).get,r)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVLBbtswDD1bX@GdLKWMYTlpi2TT7hsG7LAdhgk6KImcKrElQ5brZj@f0XbWdheJfHyknki2l/jk3ep6tU3rQ0xd37SXVHepI1XwTWqjCdH7uktvhDb4Q7@PI8WQBjoRtDsaqI0jrZAuDz5uCqrhzCofUg0htU5SKUsolVqUwBmgt1KLFUgOK@BKwXrCCrVYKygnmwOHBwXyAXn/4o@IccQe32FrWE8Yx3ut3rLv4R5RPKf6JVOjmDNKSRsamCJe1LrZHXSqt4Y2tKOaMZhulMEYIwdTpZHWcBAF25LkKGrbRfrHtnTh8uHJBENrIThSMYEk01/H8i2SJ6@H59H3WHmEkgFeRJ3vfXuhDIoRGVkB9v@xElulWiKqPgg@I4mFkzjiK3dh2cNRcnW3Xz7fQsh2FyrtpwLsZ76BExqnzxvFsHYtMfNdneRF8Ju1C0afZ3uYWGJ@lMw1X4QoXuXgZOkgB/ysumlMKhHpAIc7zl5lxEtraMWE6GLY7r2L1vVmjgYT@@DSirxzBnKzMp2RnXC5d6ajtCyAF9j9nXxrtzTPuqZnJrfbJX@bo3VtHynLu7a2kWYfM4ZzU2JDNIrbMTJ1F1m4ijsmJ3l6lqfwF22wDrOy/OSR0uiWHux@flAWUOJernF3HuARNuN@ZV@@//z949vXX8uMsfxoIgSc/PX6Fw)

Sample test:

```python
In: (1,1);(8,1);(4,4);(5,8);(4,11);(5,15);(1,18);(8,18)
Out: 
IIIIOOOOLL
TXOOOOOOXL
TTOOOOOOTL
TOOIOOOOTT
TOOIXOOTTI
TTTITOOTTI
TTTITTTTII
OOTTTTTTII
OOTTTXOOII
TTTTOOOOII
TTTTOOOOII
TTTTXTOOII
ITTTTTTTII
ITTTTTTTII
IITTTLLTTI
IITOOXLTTI
IITOOTLTTI
IITTLTTTTI
IXTLLTJTXI
ILLLLLJJJI
```

Comment: Oh my - this is amazing.  Thanks for the wonderful write up, and nice work!